# PayUBiz - Android: getting Mandatory param hash is missing

Tags: android, hash, hashcode, payu, payumoney

I'm integrating PayUBiz in my Android application. I have downloaded sample app from [here.](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-SDK-Sample-App)

It's working fine in test environment. While putting live merchantId and other things like my server url for generating hash, it won't work. It gives **"Mandatory param hash is missing"**.

What I have tried is like below.

Step-1: calling **makePayment** method.

```
private void makePayment() {
    int environment = PayuConstants.PRODUCTION_ENV;
    double totalProductPrice = 1.0;
    double conveniencePrice = 0.0;
    double totalPayableAmount = totalProductPrice + (totalProductPrice * (conveniencePrice / 100));
    //int environment = PayuConstants.STAGING_ENV;

    sharedPref = new UserSharedPref(this);

    userCredentials = merchantKey + ":" + sharedPref.getUserEmail();

    mPaymentParams = new PaymentParams();

    mPaymentParams.setKey(merchantKey);
    mPaymentParams.setAmount(String.valueOf(totalPayableAmount));
    mPaymentParams.setProductInfo("Our Store");
    mPaymentParams.setFirstName(sharedPref.getUserName());
    mPaymentParams.setEmail(sharedPref.getUserEmail());
    mPaymentParams.setTxnId("" + System.currentTimeMillis());
    mPaymentParams.setSurl("https://payu.herokuapp.com/success");
    mPaymentParams.setFurl("https://payu.herokuapp.com/failure");
    mPaymentParams.setUdf1("");
    mPaymentParams.setUdf2("");
    mPaymentParams.setUdf3("");
    mPaymentParams.setUdf4("");
    mPaymentParams.setUdf5("");
    mPaymentParams.setUserCredentials(userCredentials);
    //TODO Sets the payment environment in PayuConfig object
    payuConfig = new PayuConfig();
    payuConfig.setEnvironment(environment);
    //TODO It is recommended to generate hash from server only. Keep your key and salt in server side hash generation code.
    generatePayUHashFromServer(mPaymentParams);
}
```

Step-2: calling **generatePayUHashFromServer** method.

```
private void generatePayUHashFromServer(PaymentParams mPaymentParams) {
    StringBuffer postParamsBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.KEY, mPaymentParams.getKey()));
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.AMOUNT, mPaymentParams.getAmount()));
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.TXNID, mPaymentParams.getTxnId()));
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.EMAIL, null == mPaymentParams.getEmail() ? "" : mPaymentParams.getEmail()));
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.PRODUCT_INFO, mPaymentParams.getProductInfo()));
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.FIRST_NAME, null == mPaymentParams.getFirstName() ? "" : mPaymentParams.getFirstName()));
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.UDF1, mPaymentParams.getUdf1() == null ? "" : mPaymentParams.getUdf1()));
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.UDF2, mPaymentParams.getUdf2() == null ? "" : mPaymentParams.getUdf2()));
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.UDF3, mPaymentParams.getUdf3() == null ? "" : mPaymentParams.getUdf3()));
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.UDF4, mPaymentParams.getUdf4() == null ? "" : mPaymentParams.getUdf4()));
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.UDF5, mPaymentParams.getUdf5() == null ? "" : mPaymentParams.getUdf5()));
    postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.USER_CREDENTIALS, mPaymentParams.getUserCredentials() == null ? PayuConstants.DEFAULT : mPaymentParams.getUserCredentials()));
    if (null != mPaymentParams.getOfferKey())
        postParamsBuffer.append(concatParams(PayuConstants.OFFER_KEY, mPaymentParams.getOfferKey()));

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("orderId", orderId);
        jsonObject.put("userId", sharedPref.getUserId());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String postParams = jsonObject.toString();
    // String postParams = postParamsBuffer.charAt(postParamsBuffer.length() - 1) == '&' ? postParamsBuffer.substring(0, postParamsBuffer.length() - 1).toString() : postParamsBuffer.toString();
    Log.e("Post PAram for Hash", postParams);
    // lets make an api call
    GetHashesFromServerTask getHashesFromServerTask = new GetHashesFromServerTask();
    getHashesFromServerTask.execute(postParams);
}
```

Step-3: calling **GetHashesFromServerTask** method.

```
private class GetHashesFromServerTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, PayuHashes> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityConfirmOrder.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected PayuHashes doInBackground(String... postParams) {
        PayuHashes payuHashes = new PayuHashes();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(AppConstant.BASE_URL + "/payment/getPaymentData");
            String postParam = postParams[0];
            Log.e("Post Params", postParams[0]);
            byte[] postParamsByte = postParam.getBytes("UTF-8");

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postParamsByte.length));
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.getOutputStream().write(postParamsByte);

            InputStream responseInputStream = conn.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer responseStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            byte[] byteContainer = new byte[1024];
            for (int i; (i = responseInputStream.read(byteContainer)) != -1; ) {
                responseStringBuffer.append(new String(byteContainer, 0, i));
            }
            Log.e("Hash Response:::", responseStringBuffer.toString());

            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseStringBuffer.toString());

            Iterator<String> payuHashIterator = response.keys();
            while (payuHashIterator.hasNext()) {
                String key = payuHashIterator.next();
                switch (key) {
                    case "payment_hash":
                        payuHashes.setPaymentHash(response.getString(key));
                        break;
                    case "vas_for_mobile_sdk_hash":
                        payuHashes.setVasForMobileSdkHash(response.getString(key));
                        break;
                    case "payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk_hash":
                        payuHashes.setPaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSdkHash(response.getString(key));
                        break;

                    case "delete_user_card_hash":
                        payuHashes.setDeleteCardHash(response.getString(key));
                        break;
                    case "get_user_cards_hash":
                        payuHashes.setStoredCardsHash(response.getString(key));
                        break;
                    case "edit_user_card_hash":
                        payuHashes.setEditCardHash(response.getString(key));
                        break;
                    case "save_user_card_hash":
                        payuHashes.setSaveCardHash(response.getString(key));
                        break;

                    case "check_offer_status_hash":
                        payuHashes.setCheckOfferStatusHash(response.getString(key));
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return payuHashes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(PayuHashes payuHashes) {
        super.onPostExecute(payuHashes);

        progressDialog.dismiss();
        launchSdkUI(payuHashes);
    }
}
```

Step-4: Other methods

```
public void launchSdkUI(PayuHashes payuHashes) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityConfirmOrder.this, PayUBaseActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayuConstants.PAYU_CONFIG, payuConfig);
    intent.putExtra(PayuConstants.PAYMENT_PARAMS, mPaymentParams);
    intent.putExtra(PayuConstants.PAYU_HASHES, payuHashes);
    intent.putExtra(PayuConstants.SALT, merchantSalt);
    intent.putExtra("PaymentType", "PAYU");
    startActivityForResult(intent, PayuConstants.PAYU_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == PayuConstants.PAYU_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (data != null) {
            Log.e("PayuResponse", data.getStringExtra("payu_response"));

            try {
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(data.getStringExtra("payu_response"));
                if (responseObject != null) {
                    if (responseObject.optString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("failure")) {

                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failure..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else {
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.could_not_receive_data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.could_not_receive_data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.could_not_receive_data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.could_not_receive_data), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("Log MSg", "No Payu SDK Request Code");
    }
}

protected String concatParams(String key, String value) {
    return key + "=" + value + "&";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In android app there are 3 mandatory hash keys you have to set else you will get error "mandatory hash key missing". Make sure you have set this 3 keys to payuHashes object.

1. payuHashes.setPaymentHash(response.getString(key));
2. payuHashes.setVasForMobileSdkHash(response.getString(key));
3. payuHashes.setPaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSdkHash(response.getString(key));

Answer (score 0):

**Mandatory Param Hash is missing**

This error comes when merchant is not generating the `PaymentRelatedDetailsForMobileSDK`
hash from their server and not being passed to call PayU’s Webservice.

Below is the formula to generate this hash: `sha512(key|command|var1|salt)`

`Key` - Merchant key/Test key

`Command` - payment_related_details_for_mobile_sdk

`Var1` - default/user_credentials

`Salt` - Merchant salt/Test salt

set `payuHashes.setVasForMobileSdkHash(hash);` with same generated hash

see the no. 2 and 5 errors in this [link](https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/Generic-Issues-Faced-During-Mobile-Integrations).